# How does one isolate and test dynamically created classes in rspec

Tags: rspec

How to properly create a new isolated class for each test, using rspec 3.9.0 ?

Here's a test case:

```rb
describe 'Dynamic Class Creation' do

  it "should have dynamically created class 'One'" do
    class One; end
    expect(One).to be_an_instance_of(Class)
  end

  it "should not have class 'One' and raise 'uninitialized constant One' error" do
    expect { One }.to raise_error(an_instance_of(NameError).and having_attributes(message: 'uninitialized constant One'))
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, i actually figured out how to solve my own problem. I'll post solution here, for anyone else who needs it:

```rb
describe 'Dynamic Class Creation' do

  after :each do
    Object.send(:remove_const, :One) if Object.const_defined?(:One)
  end

  it "should have dynamically created class 'One'" do
    class One; end
    expect(One).to be_an_instance_of(Class)
  end

  it "should raise 'uninitialized constant One' error" do
    expect { One }.to raise_error(an_instance_of(NameError).and having_attributes(message: 'uninitialized constant One'))
  end

end
```